# Join multiple columns into one and getting upcoming expiration dates

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have an table that looks like this

```
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+
| licxp1       | licxp2     | licxp3     | licxp4     |
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 2014-12-18   | 2014-10-29 | 2014-12-11 | 2014-12-01 |
| 2014-12-29   | 2014-10-22 | 2014-12-18 | 2014-12-15 |
| 2014-12-18   | 2014-11-18 | 2014-12-17 | 2014-12-12 |
| 2014-12-27   | 2014-12-19 | 2014-12-18 | 2014-12-07 |
| 2014-12-18   | 2014-12-18 | 2014-12-19 | 2014-12-05 |
| 2014-12-23   | 2014-12-18 | 2014-12-18 | 2014-12-16 |
| 2014-12-18   | 2014-12-18 | 2014-12-18 | 2014-12-18 |
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

And I need it to look like this while getting the First name from another table.

```
+---------------+--------------+
| Name          | Expring lics |
+---------------+--------------+
| John Doe      | 2014-10-29   |
| Johnny Cash   | 2014-10-22   |
| Bruice Willis | 2014-11-18   |
| Led Zeplin    | 2014-12-19   |
| Def leapord   | 2014-12-18   |
| Iron Madden   | 2014-12-18   |
| etc.          | 2014-12-18   |
+---------------+--------------+
```

The `Expring lics` field gets all the upcoming expiration that are 15 days from today from the license table.

Also I need it to repeat for example if there are 2 licenses for John Doe I need it to display like this:

```
+---------------+------------+
| John Doe      | 2014-10-10 |
| John Doe      | 2014-10-21 |
| John Doe      | 2014-10-27 |
| John Doe      | 2014-10-20 |
| John Doe      | 2014-10-22 |
| Johnny Cash   | 2014-10-21 |
| Bruice Willis | 2014-11-18 |
| Led Zeplin    | 2014-12-19 |
| Def leapord   | 2014-12-18 |
| Iron Madden   | 2014-12-18 |
| etc.          | 2014-12-18 |
+---------------+------------+
```

Ask me anything I'm very new to mysql so I will try my hardest

So I have an table that looks like this

```
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+
| licxp1       | licxp2     | licxp3     | licxp4     |
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 2014-12-18   | 2014-10-29 | 2014-12-11 | 2014-12-01 |
| 2014-12-29   | 2014-10-22 | 2014-12-18 | 2014-12-15 |
| 2014-12-18   | 2014-11-18 | 2014-12-17 | 2014-12-12 |
| 2014-12-27   | 2014-12-19 | 2014-12-18 | 2014-12-07 |
| 2014-12-18   | 2014-12-18 | 2014-12-19 | 2014-12-05 |
| 2014-12-23   | 2014-12-18 | 2014-12-18 | 2014-12-16 |
| 2014-12-18   | 2014-12-18 | 2014-12-18 | 2014-12-18 |
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

And I need it to look like this while getting the First name from another table.

```
+---------------+--------------+
| Name          | Expring lics |
+---------------+--------------+
| John Doe      | 2014-10-29   |
| Johnny Cash   | 2014-10-22   |
| Bruice Willis | 2014-11-18   |
| Led Zeplin    | 2014-12-19   |
| Def leapord   | 2014-12-18   |
| Iron Madden   | 2014-12-18   |
| etc.          | 2014-12-18   |
+---------------+--------------+
```

The `Expring lics` field gets all the upcoming expiration that are 15 days from today from the license table.

Also I need it to repeat for example if there are 2 licenses for John Doe I need it to display like this:

```
+---------------+------------+
| John Doe      | 2014-10-10 |
| John Doe      | 2014-10-21 |
| John Doe      | 2014-10-27 |
| John Doe      | 2014-10-20 |
| John Doe      | 2014-10-22 |
| Johnny Cash   | 2014-10-21 |
| Bruice Willis | 2014-11-18 |
| Led Zeplin    | 2014-12-19 |
| Def leapord   | 2014-12-18 |
| Iron Madden   | 2014-12-18 |
| etc.          | 2014-12-18 |
+---------------+------------+
```

Ask me anything I'm very new to mysql so I will try my hardest

```
SELECT
id_1.full_name,
id_1.hire_date,
id_1.active,
id.professional_license,
id.license_verification,
id.cpr,
id.drivers_license,
id.car_insurance,
id.inital_competemcy_checklist,
id.annual_performance,
id.hand_washing,
id.pain_assessment,
id.competency_ev_glucometer,
id.glucometer_competency
FROM
registered_nurses id_1 INNER JOIN licenses id ON id_1.id = id.id
WHERE
id.professional_license,  id.license_verification,
id.cpr,id.drivers_license,
id.car_insurance, id.inital_competemcy_checklist,
id.inital_competemcy_checklist,
id.competency_ev_glucometer,
glucometer_competency     >=            DATE(now())
 AND
 id.professional_license,         
 id.license_verification,
 id.cpr,id.drivers_license,
 id.car_insurance, 
 id.inital_competemcy_checklist,
 id.competency_ev_glucometer,  
 glucometer_competency 
  <= DATE_ADD(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
 ORDER BY
 id.id
                                                                                            <=   DATE_ADD(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
 ORDER BY
 id.id
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you show us the SQL that you have tried (and tell us why the results were unsatisfactory)? Also show us the research you have done, so we don't duplicate your effort.

Comment: just added the code Taryn. Thanks in advance!

Comment: where did you get this question from ? Is it from your own project ?

Comment: yes sir it is a new project im working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use joins

syntax:

```
SELECT table1.column1, table2.column2...
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.common_field = table2.common_field;


SELECT users.unm,licenses.licxp1 FROM licenses INNER JOIN users ON licenses.uid = users.uid 
where licenses.licxp1 <= DATE_ADD(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 5 DAY);
```

Comment: how do i combine all the columns together?

Comment: SELECT users.unm,licenses.licxp1
FROM licenses
INNER JOIN users
ON licenses.uid = users.uid where 
licenses.licxp1 <= DATE_ADD(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 5 DAY);